# Скрыть ссылку при открытии браузера

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь открыть ссылку в браузере.

Очень нужно чтобы при открытии в браузере ссылки  не было видно.

//
делаю так

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                    
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://"));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Браузер это часть системы и вы не можете на него никак повлиять. Все ссылки передаваемые в браузер будут отображаться. Есть три варианта открытия ссылок в вашем приложении:

1. передавать через интент так как сделали это вы
2. использовать webview и показывать все внутри приложения
3. использовать custom chrome tabs

Так как 2 вариант это 1 вариант но на минималках, то в нем по-умолчанию ссылки видны тоже. Поэтому единственный доступный вам вариант по открытию ссылок мне кажется будет WebView. Этот виджет можно разместить внутри активности/фрагмента где например не будет тулбара вообще. И тогда вы сможете только отобразить содержимое страницы без отображения адреса. Вот есть две статьи по работе с данным виджетом: [ссылка_1](https://www.journaldev.com/9333/android-webview-example-tutorial) и [ссылка_2](https://javadevblog.com/rabota-s-webview-v-android-primer-i-opisanie-vozmozhnostej.html). [Документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview) по данному виджету.